# Convert range to image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking the way to save GAS range as a picture (jpg). Something similar to Excel VBA

```
Range("MainMatrixName").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture ' copy Excel selection
```

Comment: There is no API in Google Apps Script to do this, if that is what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

no such thing in apps script.
you could try coding the following but it will save as pdf not jpg:

1. have a blank spreadsheet or create one
2. copy the wanted range to the spreadsheet in A1. remove unneeded rows and columns, flush.
3. get spreadsheet as pdf.

all steps are doable in apps script.